# Display nth row from table DB in Java using getString?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I want to show data from a Table Database using SQLite in JAVA
my code:

```
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM DIC";

            rs = st.executeQuery(sql); 

            System.out.println("row 1: " + rs.getString("WORD")); // WORD is a column label
            System.out.println("row 3: " + rs.getString("WORD"))
```

With DIC is my table
so How do I can show value in nth row ( ex: 2nd, 3th,.. row)??? 
Specifically, I want my code print out as desired. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
       String sql = "SELECT * FROM DIC";

        rs = st.executeQuery(sql); 

        int rowCount = 0;

        while(rs.next){ 
             rowCount++ 
            if(rowCount == ?) {

                System.out.println("row 1: " + rs.getString("WORD"));  
                System.out.println("row 3: " + rs.getString("WORD"))
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `OFFSET` in you query and use prepared statement

```
SELECT mycol FROM DIC ORDER BY mycol LIMIT 1 OFFSET ?;
```

And you need to bind it as

```
stmt.setInt(1,nth_row);
```